# How to get the launcher to stay and hide? 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, autohide

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. My launcher keeps on hiding when I'm on the desktop. But I want it to stay out. And when I'm using programs I want it to hide. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even though i am a newer, but i have some ideas that they can solove your problem,

click the right key of the Mouse(or touch board) , then click the option "change the Background of the desktop", choose the option card " Behavior" , there is the settings of the "hide or display the LAUNCHER",,

IF you have try this, and it doesn't work eiher, it may the system's fault, so, if you reinstall the Ubuntu 12.04 iso from a USB disk

(mine is also the 12.04, now i am try to update to the lastest Ubuntu 12.10)

Answer (score 0):

On previous versions of Ubuntu, the Unity launcher had this "Dodge" feature you're talking about.

It was removed from the latest versions for some reason. I guess it might have been a stability issue. In fact I did have issues with the dodge feature (the launcher remaining unhidden).

Since you're on 12.04, you can reinstall this feature if you wish. You'll have to add a PPA and install a package. Step by step instructions:

1. Open a terminal and type `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ikarosdev/unity-revamped`
2. followed by `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
3. Log out and in again.

If you experience problems, you may revert back to the standard behaviour with the following commands:

1. sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
2. sudo ppa-purge ppa:ikarosdev/unity-revamped

Source: [[How To] Enable Unity Launcher Dodge in Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/enable-dodge-unity-launcher-ubuntu-12-04)